# Run different testcases using panel button in CANoe

Tags: panel, testcase, capl, canoe

I have the different test cases developed in test environment using CAPL.
Now I want to run all the testcases designed in CANoe. It should run using a button from panel in CANoe.

Can anyone give an alternative solution to access the testcases in panel from just only one button?

Comment: You can specify the start/stop events of test modules and units in the test configuration dialog.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. **Easy way**: Go to the configuration of the Test Module. Enable the Start condition using a system variable. Now you can attach this system variable to a control in your Panel and you can start the test case from the panel. In this method, you can only Start a Test case. It is not possible to stop a test case using system variable.
2. **Hard way**: You can develop a .NET Panel (how-to available under chapter "*.NET Panels*") and then access the CANoe config via COM. In this method, you can have complete control over your test cases (start, stop, resume, etc.)

Comment: Consider marking this question as answered if you have received the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I understand that the solution worked. What I told was, you can mark your question as "Answered" by clicking the "Tick" button to the left of my answer. For more details : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235